# Как объединить две таблицы средствами sql запросов?

Tags: sqlite, mysql

Как объединить две таблицы средствами sql запросов?
Есть такая таблица:

```
CREATE TABLE [dolgnosty] (
  [id] INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
  [id_stavka] INTEGER, 
  [dolgnost] VARCHAR(80));
```

К этой таблице должна быть присоединена эта:

```
CREATE TABLE [stavky] (
  [id] INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
  [id_dolgnost] INTEGER,   
  [id_point] INTEGER,
  [id_period] INTEGER,
  [stavka] FLOAT);
```

Т.е. таблица `dolgnosty` неизменна, а таблица `stavky` меняется, но, все это должно показываться одной таблицей! Как это сделать?

Comment: Чем этот вопрос отличается от вашего предыдущего?

* [Как написать sql запрос, объединяющий две таблицы?][1]


  [1]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/35523/

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT a.id, a.id_stavka, a.dolgnost, b.id AS stavki_id, b.id_point, b.id_period, b.stavka
FROM table1 AS a
LEFT JOIN table2 AS b ON b.id = a.id_dolgnost
WHERE ...
```